# Extracting values from json in Splunk using spath

Tags: json, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying following query

`| makeresults | eval _raw="{\"records\":[{\"Name\":\"name\"},{\"Name\":\"worst_food\",\"Value\":\"salad\"},{\"Name\":\"ex-wife\",\"Value\":\"Tammy\"}]}" | spath`

this returns table as like below in Splunk.

`records{}.name   records().value
 name             salad
 worst_food       Tammy
 ex-wife`

But i am expecting value as like

`records{}.name   records().value
 name
 worst_food       salad
 ex-wife          Tammy`

Anyone experienced this issue? could you please share some knowledge that how to derive expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dhana

Can you please try this?

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="{\"records\":[{\"Name\":\"name\"},{\"Name\":\"worst_food\",\"Value\":\"salad\"},{\"Name\":\"ex-wife\",\"Value\":\"Tammy\"}]}" 
| spath path=records{} output=records | mvexpand records | rename records as _raw | kv | table Name Value
```

Thanks